# Limits users to see each other

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I have a ejabberd server with about 40 clients, I want to limit, for example developers, to unable to see guys in selling department.

I found Shared Roster Groups but it can add persons to specified group, not more than it, you can't set privileges on group to don't see another group.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Take look at [mod_filter](https://www.ejabberd.im/mod_filter?q=mod_filter). I didn't use it on my own but it looks like it may fit your problem. If not you can consider [imlementing your own ejabberd module](http://metajack.im/2008/08/28/writing-ejabberd-modules-presence-storms/) with necessary functionality.